# css div horizontal alignment

Tags: html, css

I have four divs inside a container div. The 4 divs should be aligned horizontall next to each other, but as of now only three of them are aligning horizontally. The fourth div breaks to the next line.

Here's the HTML markup:

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
        <div id="standards">
            <h5><strong>My Energy Standards</strong></h5>
        </div>
        <div id="years">
            <h5><strong>My Study Periods</strong></h5>
            <div id="col-1"></div>
            <div id="col-2"></div>
            <div id="col-3"></div>
            <div id="col-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The 4 divs are the #col-1,2,3, and 4.

Here's the CSS markup:

```
    #years{
    overflow: auto;
}
#col-1, #col-2, #col-3, #col-4{
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

An image to go the for the visuals:

[image]

The years div will eventually have the same border as the standards div. First I needed to figure out why its not doing what I want it to do. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your parent div width is too small to fit the 4 divs. Are you trying to add a horizontal scroll ?

Comment: try increasing your width  of the container by 20 px

Comment: The issue seemed to be with the width of the columns inherently provided by Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be only part of the html being used (which is usually good) but in this case i think it is a width issue further up the chain of html/css that is specified that is causing your column to line break.

You need to look through your html and css at whatever container that is smaller than the size of the columns you are making and expand its width to allow the fourth column to align properly.